# Functions of nested class thinks 'self' as an argument - Python

Tags: python, class, arguments, typeerror, inner-classes

I'm trying to make a game of tic-tac-toe.

I have one class, Player, and one nested class, Check, in it.

This is my full code:

```
class Player: # Player class
'''this is a class for the player in a tic-tac-toe game'''

def __init__(self, counter): # initialize
    self.counter = counter # set player counter

def place(self, x, y): # functions directly interfering with data can global
    '''this function helps with placing counters on the grid'''
    global grid
    grid[y][x] = self.counter

class Check:
    '''checks if a player wins or loses'''

    def check_vertical(self, grid): # checking functions avoid globaling
        '''check if there are three counters in a row vertically'''
        for row in range(3):
            if grid[row][0] and grid[row][1]\
               and grid[row][2] == self.counter:
                return True

    def check_horiontal(self, grid): # checking functions avoid globaling
        '''check if there are three counters in a row horizontally'''
        for column in range(3):
            if grid[0][column] and grid[1][column]\
               and grid[2][column] == self.counter:
                return True

    def check_diagonal(self, grid): # checking functions avoid globaling
        '''check if there are three counters in a row diagonally'''
        if grid[0][0] and grid[1][1] and grid[2][2] or\
           grid[0][2] and grid[1][1] and grid[2][0] == self.counter:
            return True

    def check_all(self, grid):
        '''check if there are three counters in a row in any direction'''
        return (self.check_vertical(self, grid) or\
                self.check_horizontal(self, grid) or\
                self.check_diagonal(self, grid))
```

So, when I try to test it in the shell:

```
>>> player = Player("O")
>>> player.Check.check_all(tic_tac_toe_grid)
```

Python throws an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#34>", line 1, in <module>
    a.Check.check_all(grid)
TypeError: check_all() missing 1 required positional argument: 'grid'
```

Python thinks that `self` is a required argument.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You are calling the Class method, not the instance method.  You need to instantiate `Check`, then call the method on the instance.

Comment: Please post more context. Depending on the implementation of `Check` you might need static methods, a new module, or something completely different.

Comment: Please do research on your own before asking such obvious questions. This is explained in the Python tutorial and references which come with the normal installation. Programming is not about spoon-feeding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of this has anything to do with `Check` being a nested class.

First, Python thinks that `self` is a required argument because it is. You explicitly declared it as a parameter:

```
def check_all(self, grid):
```

When you call methods normally, on an instance of a class, like `thingy.method(foo)`, Python will turn that `thingy` into the `self`.

But you're not calling the method on an instance of `Check`, you're calling it on `Check` itself. That's legal, but unusual. And when you do it, you need to explicitly pass an instance to be the `self`.

And there's your real problem—you don't even *have* an instance. And presumably you created the class, with attributes and an `__init__` method and everything, because you needed instances of that class. (If you *don't* need a class, then you should get rid of the class and just make the functions methods of `Player`, or top-level functions.)

So, just getting rid of this error is easy:

```
player.Check().check_all(tic_tac_toe_grid)
```

But what you almost certainly *want* to do is to create a `Check()` instance somewhere that you can use when you need it. Does each Player own a single Check? Then something like this:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, counter): # initialize
        self.counter = counter # set player counter
        self.check = Check()
```

And then you can use it:

```
player.check.check_all(tic_tac_toe_grid)
```

I don't actually know if that's what your object model is supposed to be, but hopefully you do.

Answer (score 0):

`Check` is a nested class in `Player` and you can access it using `Player.Check` or using `Player` instances - in your case `player`.

A nested class behaves just the same as a normal class. Its methods still require an instance. The `self` parameter to the method tells you that it operates on instances. If you don't need any state on that class, you have two options:

1. Move all methods from `Check` to its own module and place the functions in there without any class. Or...
2. Make all methods in `Check` static (`@staticmethod`). This is rather an antipattern though.

Comment: Wow, it actually works! But now, the shell throws an `AttributeError` because `self.counter` is not in its scope. It is in the `Player` class's scope. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @HUAN5235 I don't know what `counter` stands for. It is not available from within `Check` because it's an attribute on `Player` instances. Depending on the context you might want to pass it as a parameter or merge the two classes into one.